# После переноса modx на локальную не подходит логин/пароль от админки?

Tags: сервер, modx

После переноса *modx* на локальную не подходит логин/пароль от админки.

На хостинге авторизация админа проходит успешно, а на локальной пишет что неверный логин или пароль.
Почему могло так произойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит сравнить значения полей `password` и `salt` в обоих таблицах `префикс_users`. Попробовать восстановить пароль, указав в `префикс_user_attributes` e-mail администратора.

Также, возможно проблема связана, с тем, что при переносе имелись залогиненые пользователи. Загляните в таблицу `префикс_session` и приведите  её в дефолтное состояние:

вместо **префикс_session** - имя таблице с Вашим префиксом. По умолчанию это **modx_session**.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `префикс_session`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `префикс_session` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `access` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `access` (`access`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: после salt есть только в табл. users и оно != password.  что сранить в табл user_attributes Тогда не понятно ибо там не салд не пасс... сессию сбросил - ничего не поменяло

Comment: @Stein_ странно, что записи в таблицах разные. Вы же на хостинге делаете дамп БД и заливаете его на `localhost`? В  `user_attributes` не надо ничего сравнивать, там можно указать `e-mail` администратора (если не был указан) и восстановить доступ с помощью "забыли пароль". После этого попробовать войти по новому паролю.

Comment: Изменил почту , в базе все совпадения сменил и все равно пишет что такого пользователя с почтой нету, как будто админка совсем не видит пользовательских данных

Answer (score 0):

Советую проверить настройку base_url и прочие урлы в файле конфиги. У меня было такое что авторизация происходила, но кукисы ставились не на путь "/" а на "/ru/" и соответственно для админки ("/manager/") были недоступны.